# meaning of sentence with "include __ other than __" structure

Tags: meaning, sentence

In the below sentence,

> The mission of the entity may include goals other than maximizing profit.

is it implied that "maximizing profit" is a goal of the entity OR is it referring to only non-profit-maximizing goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence suggests that "maximizing profit" is *expected* to be a goal of the entity, but it does not imply that it actually *will* be a goal of the entity.

As you suggested, a non-profit organization will not have "maximizing profit" as a goal, though many will aim to raise as much money as they can to further their other aims. And of course an entity might exist only to distribute money provided by a different entity.

Comment: But it could also imply 'different goals _as well as_ maximising profit'.

Comment: It's contingent on context. You could probably say something like "The entity is not supposed to make a significant profit. The mission of the entity may include goals other than maximizing profit." But equally you could say "The entity is expected to make a profit. The mission of the entity may include goals other than maximizing profit."

Comment: This was a stand-alone sentence as an answer choice to a multiple choice question. It seemed like it could be interpreted both ways, so this prompted a sanity check. Thank for everyone's input!